# How do I stop a server call when a user scrolls too quickly?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uitableview, scroll

I am developing an iPhone application that retrieves photos from a server and presents them on the screen similar to the way Pulse News Reader presents its articles. I have a vertically scrolling `UITableView` and each `UITableViewCell` contains its own custom `UITableView` instance that allows the user to thumb through photos horizontally.

The way that I currently populate the horizontally-scrolling table is by making a server call in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of the vertically-scrolling table. Whenever a new cell comes into the view, I send a request for that particular cell's photos, as in the code below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EventCell";

    EventViewCell *cell = (EventViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[EventViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Event *event = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self performPhotoFetchForEventID:event.id inCell:cell withRetries:3];

    return cell;
}
```

This solution works really well when the user scrolls through the vertical table slowly, however if the user scrolls quickly or "flicks" through the list, it begins to break down. Essentially, if the user scrolls through X events really quickly, the app will fire off X server requests and return all of the results, even though the app's view only needs the results of at most three of those requests. This occasionally causes pictures to show up in the wrong rows, or show a delay.

**How can I prevent / cancel my server requests from firing if the user scrolls too quickly. Or is there a better way to implement this to get the desired effect?**

Answer (score 4):

> This occasionally causes pictures to show up in the wrong rows

Before tackling other parts of your problem, you should try to understand why this is happening.

From my experience, (of course depends on the size of the image), it's better to just get the Image from the server and not cancel it. Although you should keep something in mind:

- Cache it once you have it, and make sure to check your cache before asking for a new. You can use a `NSDictionary` and the key be the image's URL.
- Async calls. You shouldn't block/stress your UI Thread with the Request/Cache part. Use `NSOperations` and `NSOperationQueue` to create small workers to take care of the request and caching. Once you get it, just update your `UIImageView`.
- Leave a Placeholder while the Image is being fetch. This shows the user that something is happening.
- Update your DataSource and not your Cells. The reason why, is that if you are seeing rows [0,1,2,3,4,5] and you scroll and now you are seeing rows [40,41,42,43,44,45], when the responses comes with the images for the first rows, the cells have been long gone (might be the problem your experiencing with the Images on the wrong places).
- Finally, and because you mention Pulse News, why not learn a bit with them? Use [this](http://eng.pulse.me/concurrent-downloads-using-nsoperationqueues/) link to access their Engineering Page and learn a bit about downloading images. :)

Comment: +1 dude , because it was too lengthy to explain here on SO.BUt you did  so well.

Comment: @Jacky Boy, thank you for the great response - voted up for all the great tips and suggestions. I will spend some time going through your recommendations and report back here with my findings.

Comment: Don't forget to check the sample code they give. (it's a bit tricky, but it should help you a lot).

Comment: @JackyBoy, I moved the photos request to a single call in the `viewDidLoad` method and new photos to a persistent store using Core Data. Now, in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I am simply getting the photos with the appropriate Core Data request. Photos are showing up in the correct rows and are being cached properly now. Thank you for pushing me in the right direction!

Comment: You are storing the request in Core Data (URL for example) or the actual photo?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NSUrlConnection to retrieve images in a lazy loading mode, you can send this command to the connection:

```
[connection cancel];
```

[Here the Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score -1):

You should not, my all means, create photo request on every cellForRowAtIndexPath:. You should use async image caching lib, there are few of them: I use JMImageCache.